# Problem with echo values from database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, json

I inserted on a row of database table values, now I want echo them with json_encode, but I have following error:

**PHP:**

```
$name_tour = $this->input->post('tour_name');
$query     = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE '$name_tour' ORDER BY id desc");
$data      = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data_rp = json_decode($row->residence_p, true);
    $data[]  = array(
        'residence_p' => $data_rp,
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
echo '<p>';
var_dump($data);
```

**Output above php code:**

```
[{"residence_p":null}] // This is output of json_encode($data)

array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["residence_p"]=> NULL } } // This is output of var_dump($data)
```

**Data in database:(this data insert by json_encode)**

```
[{
    "start_date": ["1111", "2222"],
    "end_date": ["1111", "2222"],
    "price_change": ["1111", "2222"]
}, {
    "start_date": ["3333", "444"],
    "end_date": ["3333", "4444"],
    "price_change": ["3333", "4444"]
}, {
    "start_date": ["5555", "6666"],
    "end_date": ["5555", "6666"],
    "price_change": ["5555", "6666"]
},]
```

What do i do?

Comment: What is the error? What were you expecting to see?

Comment: I want get data from inside database, please see to code it is clear that, what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `,` before the last `]`, otherwise the data is invalid JSON which cannot be correctly parsed by `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
$data_rp = json_decode($row->residence_p, true);
```

Did you really store json data in your database? I doubt it, but if you did DON'T! Doing that defeats the entire purpose of having a database with columns.

Comment: I put in post data inside database.

Comment: Don't do that!!! Make columns `start_date`, `end_date`, and `price_change`, do not store json data in a database, you will regret it later if you do.